# Why is gdal.Translate returning array of zeroes?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, clip, extents

I'm trying to clip a dataset based on a bounding box, and return an object, and it seems to be working as the output size are about as expected.

However, the resulting dataset is a black image (i.e. an array of zeroes) when I read it as an array.

Here is the code:

```
def clip_band(band, UL, BR):
    #GDAL wants (lng, lat) coordinates
    coords_factor = 10**4
    if UL[0] > BR[0]: 
        print("Invalid window, longitude")
        return None
    elif UL[1] < BR[1]:
        print("Invalid window, latitude")
        return None
    output_band = gdal.Translate('/vsimem/in_memory_output.tif', band,
                             projWin = [UL[0]*coords_factor, UL[1]*coords_factor, 
                            BR[0]*coords_factor, BR[1]*coords_factor],
                            outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32)

    return output_band
```

when I do something like `red_band = clip_band(red_band, UL=(-58.88411,-34.60202),BR=(-58.49080,-34.80839))`

I get an array of shape 393 x 206, while the original is 10980 x 10980 but it seems to contain no information, while the original of course is what I'd expect to see from the area.

Comment: [GDAL Python Gotcha](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#saving-and-closing-datasets-datasources). Close & del `output_band` then reopen `/vsimem/in_memory_output.tif'` for reading.

Comment: Unfortunately its the same output, everything works fine again but the output as an array is an array of zeroes

Comment: `gdal.Translate()` takes in a `Dataset` object as input or a filepath - not a `Band`- are you sure you have the correct input type? Also if your output tif has the same spatial reference as the input image (i.e. you're not projecting the result), `projWin` should be `srcWin` as well